# How to setup absolute position of a DIV with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, position

I have a code like that:

```
$('#lol').css({ position: "absolute",

        marginLeft: 0, marginTop: 0,

        top: 0, left: 0});
```

The problem is that my div is positioned relatively, so it is point 0 of a div rather than the entire window. Why is that?

Comment: Why is what? Why is your div relatively positioned? Or why does absolute positioning work in this way?

Comment: The point of language is to communicate in a clear and unambiguous way. It should not involve guessing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As pointed out in the other answers, at least one of the parent element of `#lol` has a `position` set, that causes your element to be positioned within the parent.

A solution with jQuery would be to attach the element directly to body.

```
$('#lol').css({ 
    position: "absolute",
    marginLeft: 0, marginTop: 0,
    top: 0, left: 0
}).appendTo('body');
```

This will make it to appear top left of the window.

Comment: appendTo, but otherwise great!

Comment: It works perfectly! but what about scrolling? how can we run a code on scroll event? I've tried something like that: $(window).scroll(function(){ /*code here*/}); but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

> Why is that?

If you want to use `position: absolute` relatively to the entire window, you need to make sure that your `#lol` has no parent elements also positioned `absolute`, `fixed`, or `relative`.

Otherwise, any positioning you specify will take place relative to them.

Answer (score 3):

Elements that have `position: relative` or `position: absolute` will be positioned relative to the closest parent that has `position: relative` or `position: absolute`. So, if you want your element to be positioned relative to the entire window, keep it outside of any parent wrappers with relative or absolute positions.

Comment: Its child elements will be positioned absolutely within its relative parent if the child has position: absolute.

Answer (score 0):

That's just how positioning works. If you have any parent elements with any position specified the absolute positioning will happen relative to them.

If you want it to the window but can't do away with any of the other elements' positioning you'll need to remove the item from regular page flow either manually or with a bit of JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **absolute:position** on an element relative to the entire window screen than any parent of that element should not given any position values like absolute,fixed or relative,because the element will take the position relative to its parent if any position attribute is given to it.
    Hope it answer you well...:)